# How can I make the content list of a PDF expanded by default?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks, viewers

I am using pdflatex to create a rather long document. The document also has a table of contents, and the PDF naturally has some metadata of this list of contents that I can view in my PDF viewer (here: Apple Preview and Skim on OS X). The list of contents is collapsed by default, but people on the Skim mailing list told me, that this is a setting inside of the PDF. So how can I tell pdflatex to create an expanded list of contents then?

Comment: I think you are not talking about the table of contents but the bookmarks, aka outlines, of the PDF. Adobe Reader for examples shows these bookmarks at a side bar. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I guess this is correct. I don't know the exact names of this. But the side bar basically shows me the table of contents.

Comment: The exact name would be "outlines" (AFAIK used at the primary pdf documentation). But almost everybody use "bookmarks". And the tex.stackexchange tag is "{bookmarks}" too. BTW: In German the translation is "Lesezeichen". Unfortunatly "Lesezeichen" has been used for several other elements (e.g. annotations or marks to favorites).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a `pdflatex` issue.  You must be using, directly or indirectly, the `hyperref` package, which controls the PDF TOC.  To have it unfolded, just add this to the preamble of your document:

```
\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=true}
```

Comment: Maybe you could write a sentence about `bookmarkopenlevel=<number>` and e.g. link to package [bookmark](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) that supports additional bookmark features.

Comment: Perfect. That was what I was looking for!

Comment: This solution does not work for OSX Preview, which keeps collapsing the TOC in the left hand pane.