# Open \part in PDF table of contents automatically

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, viewers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the content list of a PDF expanded by default?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/how-can-i-make-the-content-list-of-a-pdf-expanded-by-default)

I am writing a thesis using LaTeX and everything is just fine. However, as my project includes three different parts for which I use the command `\part{}`. I notice that when I open the PDF file and check the contents on the left, I need to click to open the part and see the contents inside.

Is there a way of telling the PDF file to open with all the menu opened by itself?

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `hyperref` package which I presume you are, then you can set the option `bookmarksopen` to `true` either like

```
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
```

or like

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup {
  bookmarksopen = true,
}
```